# Fix SharedElementTransition animation not showing well

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm trying to create a shared elements transition animation between 2 activities with a shared `ImageView`.

The first one has a `RecyclerView` with an item click listener, and after click, it should start the other activity with the transition.

The animation works fine when closing the started activity, but it doesn't when starting it.

After tapping the item of the `RecyclerView`, it expands a bit, freezes for a bit,  and then shows a blank black "window" and then the other ImageView, but it doesn't animates fluently.

This is the code to open the other activity:

```
private void openActivity(WallpapersAdapter.WallsHolder wallsHolder, int index, final HashMap<String, String> data) {

    Toast.makeText(this,data.get(WallpapersActivity.WALL),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(wallsActivity, ViewerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("wallUrl", data.get(WallpapersActivity.WALL));
    intent.putExtra("wallName", data.get(WallpapersActivity.NAME));

    String indextext = Integer.toString(index);
    intent.putExtra("indexText", indextext);

    String transName = "view_" + indextext;
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(wallsHolder.view, transName);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            wallsActivity, wallsHolder.view, transName);

    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

}
```

**Edit:**
This is the code of the layout for the initial view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" />

    <jahirfiquitiva.project.views.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/wall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titlebg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        style="@style/AboutContent"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="#000000"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
            tools:text="Title" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 2:**
This is a video showing how it looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw52d3_ZiSb9YWc2Z1Z4MnkwNm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I faced a similar problem, but with fragments. The problem was that the transition name has to be unique for each element inside the RecyclerView. So while binding your view, set its transition name appended with position. And then send this transition name to your activity as well - where you assign this to your view in onCreate. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, but still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I wrote this short program to experiment with this... I'm animating textViews as sharedElements... And it's working... Here's what I did :

Inside my RecyclerView adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(((RecyclerViewHolder) holder).mTextView,"myTransition"+position);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            mEventListener.clicked((RecyclerViewHolder) holder);
        }
    });
}
```

MainActivity's click event from where I'm starting the other Activity

```
@Override
public void clicked(final MyAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("TRANSITION_KEY", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.mTextView));

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this, holder.mTextView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.mTextView));

    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

Other Activity's onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(textView, intent.getStringExtra("TRANSITION_KEY"));
}
```

**Solution to your specific problem**

Aside from following the previous instructions, remove the Toast inside onClick.

Add transitionSet xml in : res/transition/image_transition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet>
  <changeImageTransform/>
  <changeBounds/>
</transitionSet>
```

Remove these from your styles.xml (if they're added)

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowTransitionAnimation</item>
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
```

Comment: I tried it, but still got the same. This is how it looks (video) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw52d3_ZiSb9YWc2Z1Z4MnkwNm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh... I just watched the video you shared. And I think the problem is that the image is being reloaded (from some API) in that second activity... So while it gets loaded, you see nothing. If you're using Picasso, send the loaded image to that other activity and set it as the placeholder for that imageView.

Comment: I'm using Ion. May you help me with the "send the image to the other activity" code? I can't find a sample or something in library documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes sure! I'll update my answer with the updated code.

Comment: I actually tried Ion, and with it - there are glitches. I recommend that you try  Picasso - the same animation works flawlessly with Picasso - meaning if the image is already loaded, then we don't have to pass it to another activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82320/discussion-between-jahir-fiquitiva-and-sudo-rizwan).